# Where is Ubuntu terminal located?

Tags: command-line, eclipse

I am trying to add terminal as external tool to compile javascript with **node.js**.
I am following this [article](https://z0ltan.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/configuring-eclipse-to-run-standalone-javascript-files-using-node-jsgoogle-v8-engine/) which is based on **windows** , and i am stuck at figuring out location of terminal application.

Where is the terminal located in Ubuntu?

Comment: You don't need the terminal. You need a shell, and that would be `/bin/bash`. If you need the terminal, that would be `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`.

Comment: As above; there should already be a shortcut (from which you can copy) in the applications menu.

Comment: @muru thanks, do you know how to pass parameter bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the settings used in that post:

- command: `cmd.exe`
- working directory: `C:\WINDOWS\system32`
- arguments: `/C "cd ${container_loc} && node ${resource_name}"`

The analogue would be:

- `/bin/bash`
- (this is optional)
- `-c "cd ${container_loc} && node ${resource_name}"`

I think the following would be simpler:

- `/usr/bin/node` (or wherever your `node` is installed)
- `"${container_loc}"`
- `"${resource_name}"`

If you installed `node` using `apt-get`, then it is likely to be `/usr/bin/nodejs` and `nodejs` instead of `/usr/bin/node` and `/node`.

Answer (score 6):

```
/usr/bin/xterm
```

and

```
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

I found this location by doing a search in the file-system for "term".  Double clicked it and it worked.